# Feeding date to Azure SQL DB

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, syntax, azure-sql-database

I wanted to store an occasion in DB in the cloud. Right now, I've done it Q&D by:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
String occasion = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Then, I'm executing a query with that string in it. In my eyes, it's super, duper rookie. Is that a commonly accepted approach or is there a nicer way to store a *DateTime* typed object into Azure DB?

Comment: For one thing, persisted/serialized dates should use the round-trip date format: `{0:o}`.  Note: Please show us which Azure API's you're using to store the resulting String object...  This seems to indicate `datetime` works just fine: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/sql-databases/getting-started-w-sql-databases/#AddData

Comment: @ebyrob It's much simpler than that. I'm only executing an *insert into*. I know it's not a good approach but that's what I'm allowed to do at the moment. Not even SP are acceptable due to various limitations. :(

Comment: If there are restrictions on what commands you can run (like CREATE isn't allowed) then you should mention that in the problem statement.  Note: There's nothing wrong with serializing persistent data to Strings, we used to do it all the time in Java...  Just be sure you do it correctly (ie: Don't lose data by choosing the wrong format, yours has no time-zone.)

Answer (score 2):

Why not user the regular DateTime type ?!

Comment: That's what I intended but I got errors. Apparently, if you don't convert the *DateTime* object, there are some escape characters getting in your way and the syntax gets confused. So I had to stringify the date to make it work. Now, I'd like to know if there's a better way.

Comment: @KonradViltersten sounds like you should be using parametrized queries.  This article seems to indicate it works just like regular SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519560.aspx#Parameters.  Of course since we don't know what Azure API's you're using that's just a shot in the dark...

Comment: @ebyrob I'm not sure what you mean by "Azure API". Are you referring to the connection string? I'm executing the query against the database as I would against any other through a *SqlConnection* object and ODBC. Also, for a set of reasons (some of which are border-line idiotic but forced upon me), I can't use the parametric set up, neither. It needs to be resolved by creating an actual string and executing it. :(

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection with ODBC driver!  That's a big start.  Anything special about your connection string (like the ODBC driver portion) and any other even remotely unusual classes/functions you're interacting with to get things to work.  Note: for SqlConnection when you used SqlCommand.Parameters to set the datetime value to an nvarchar table column, I'm kind of surprised it didn't work.  For the record, are these reasons technical?  If not, please outline what you can in the question so we can answer better.

Comment: @ebyrob No technical reasons. Just a stubborn customer. I'm only allowed to create a *String* object that will be executed. Yes, that's right. My whole SQL command is supposed to consist of a single string. No room for parametrization. It's a "on-liner", so to speak.  I don't like it but for now, I'm just converting the *DateTime* object to a string using *ToString(format)*, haha.